# Not able to see background image in outlook

Tags: html, css

This is my code

```
<table background="image link" background-position="" border="0" 
cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="250" width="100%">

<tr>
<td width="10">
</td><td width="10">
</td></tr><tr>
<td height="60" width="50">
</td><td bgcolor="FFFFFF" height="60" style="text-align: center;">
<div>
 &nbsp;</div><div style="line-height: 200%;">
 <span style="font-size:28px;"><b><span style="color:#000000;"><span 
 style="font-family:georgia,serif;">Welcome </span></span> </b></span></div> 
 </td><td height="60" width="50">
 </td></tr></table>
```

I am not able to see the background image, when i open this email in outlook. I am creating this email using salesforce, please help me on this issue. I have typed image link , instead of the actual image link i am using.

Comment: hope this link might help you  https://litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-background-images-in-email

Answer (score 0):

try `background-image` instead of `background` like this

```
background-image: url("image-url.jpg");
background-position: center center; /* whatever you want */
background-repeat: no-repeat; /* or repeat */
```